# Position of button using Vue.js

Tags: html, css, vue.js, button

It's been awhile since I have been coding but I was wondering how do I position my Login button at the bottom centre of the screen and have the image displayed over it? Thanks

Code:

```
<template>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <img alt="Sportly logo" src="~@/assets/sportly.png">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h3>Login</h3>
                <button class="btn btn-primary"
                    @click="signIn">
                    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                    Sign In with Twitter
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        signIn () {
            this.$store.dispatch('signIn')
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
h3 {
    font-weight: 700;
}
button {
    background-color: #1dcaff;
    border: 1px solid  #1dcaff;
    positioning: absolute;
bottom: 0px;

}
div button:hover {
    background-color: #00aced;
    border: 1px solid  #00aced;
}
</style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is class **col-md-6**. In your case it has style: {width: 50%}. You neen another class that suits your case

Comment: thanks. Didn't realise it was bootstrap lmao. What class would that be?

Comment: Class **col-md-12** has style: {width: 100%}, by default div has {width: 100%} so in your case class is not necessary at all

Comment: so just simple css/html should do the tric?

Answer (score 0):

To center an element try :

display:flex;
justify-content: center;

or
margin:0 auto;

but you need to change col-md-6 to col-md-12